Add date interval determined from table column
I'm trying to add a number of days to a date column in an AWS Athena table, where the number of days is determined by another column.
I can add a fixed number of days to the column as:
select (current_date + interval '1' day) as Incremented_Date

but when I try the following
select (current_date + interval D_Plus day) as Incremented_Date
from
(select * from (VALUES(1),
                     (2),
                     (3),
                     (4)
                     ) as t("D_Plus"))

I get the error

mismatched input 'D_Plus'. Expecting: '+', '-', .  *

I'm hoping to get the following result:


In the documentation Date, Timestamp, and Interval Operators there is section
Rules for Specifying Intervals

A Day-Time Interval Literal is a string that denotes a single interval
value.

The value is literal so what you are trying to do won't work.
A couple options
You can add your column D_Plus as a multiplier:
select (current_date + D_Plus * interval '1' day) as Incremented_Date
from (
        select *
        from (
                VALUES(1),
                    (2),
                    (3),
                    (4)
            ) as t("D_Plus")
    )

Or you can use a DATE_ADD function:
select DATE_ADD('day', D_Plus, current_date) as Incremented_Date
from (
        select *
        from (
                VALUES(1),
                    (2),
                    (3),
                    (4)
            ) as t("D_Plus")
    )

